# How to obtain IEnumerable<ValidationResult> from ValidationAttribute in Asp Core

Tags: asp.net-core

In Asp Mvc version, it was possible to get IEnumerable on IsValid method by using IValidatableObject interface.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
// yield collection of validation results here
}
```

But in Asp Core version, we intended to use ValidationAttribute to achieve custom validations. But, available method return only single ValidationResult.

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
// custom validation
}
```

What if, we need to throw multiple ValidationResult in single event?

Answer (score 0):

The `IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext)` Method still returns `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`. There is no change in the API. Here is the API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_IValidatableObject_Validate_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040).

Comment: Actually Yes, I just lost that way.. Now I got it. Thanks a lot.